# MaterialCommunityIcons showing incorrect icon in react native bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, icons, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm following the guide from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={Feed}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => 
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) =>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
        }}
      />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Everything works, except it shows the wrong icon. 'home' icon displays sad emoji, and 'bell' icon displays sad emoji with sweat.
I tried to change `name=""`  in `<MaterialCommunityIcons>`icons and it all shows different icons that what the name suggested.
The icon that appears are also coloured, so I suspected that it might not be rendering MaterialCommunityIcons at all.

Could someone suggest what might have gone wrong please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on android.

1. I just followed the android installation
   https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android
2. In my case, I have to ignore this step which should perform in  android/app/src/main/java/...MainApplication.java

import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

new VectorIconsPackage()

(it gave me an error)

3. build the APK again.

And that's it. it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues what I did was I added the following to my `android/app/build.gradle`

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Then I ran `react-native run-android` again and my issue was fixed.
Also check out this [npm documentation on react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons/v/4.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

For solving the issue follow these steps

1. create folder called font inside android/app/src/main/assets
2. Copy all Fonts inside the node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\Fonts
3. Paste the same to the above created folder(android/app/src/main/assets/fonts)

Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't really work. It is still showing the wrong icon

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, issues might be caused by cached assets. Try clearing the cache using the following commands:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

It was happening with me, when I tried to use other libraries of the vector-icons, instaed of showing me the correct icons, it appeared japonese signs, so if you are using react-native-vector-icons in the android enviroment you have to follow those steps:

Android Setup
Option: With Gradle (recommended)
To make font management smoother on Android, use this method:

Edit android/app/build.gradle (NOT android/build.gradle) and add:

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```

To customize the fonts being copied, use:

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Specify font files
]
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```

from the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons#android-setup